# Update product price using migrate:delta

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento2-migration-tool

Why the product price dont update using migrate:delta after data migrate?
Versions: 1.9.3.2 > 2.1.7
Cache clean.
Reindex all.

Log:

```
$ sudo php bin/magento migrate:delta vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.3.2/config.xml

[2017-06-06 07:59:59][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2017-06-06 07:59:59][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2017-06-06 07:59:59][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Map Step]: started
.
[2017-06-06 07:59:59][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Map Step]: started
[2017-06-06 07:59:59][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Log Step]: started
[2017-06-06 07:59:59][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Log Step]: started
[2017-06-06 07:59:59][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
[2017-06-06 07:59:59][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
[2017-06-06 07:59:59][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
[2017-06-06 07:59:59][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
[2017-06-06 07:59:59][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: Migration completed successfully
[2017-06-06 07:59:59][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: Automatic restart in 5 sec. Use CTRL-C to abort
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incremental migration enables you to migrate only the changes made in Magento 1 since the last time you migrated data.

These changes are:

- data that customers added via storefront (created orders, reviews,
  changes in customer profiles, etc.)
- all operations with orders in the
  Magento Admin panel

[Source](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/migration/migration-migrate-data.html)